# Unexpected space

Tags: html, css

I get an unexpected space between the `Menu+Content` and the `footer`, and I don't know where it came from because I want to get rid of it. Here is the code and how it looks for me in Chrome and Firefox:

(sorry for the bad formatting, I don't know how to do it)

The index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Online Contacts</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>

       <div id="container">
         <div id="header">
           <h1>OnCo</h1>
         </div>

         <div id="menu">
           <b>Menu</b><br>
              ab<br>
              cd<br>
              ef
          </div>

          <div id="content">
             Content goes here
          </div>

         <div id="footer">
              Copyright Š joj
         </div>

      </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The CSS

```
    div {
       /*colturi rotunde*/
        border-radius: 10px; 
    }
    body{ 
       /*gradient care se repeta orizontal numai*/
       background-image:url('a.jpg');
       background-repeat:repeat-x;  
    }
    #container {
       /*bg transparent*/
       background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
       max-width:960px;
       /*centrat in pagina*/         
       margin: 0 auto;
       /*distanta dintre border si continut*/
       padding-top:15px;
       padding-right:15px;
       padding-left:15px;
       padding-bottom:15px;     
   }
   #header { 
       background-color:#FFA500;
       position: relative;
       top: -20px;
   }
   #menu{
       background-color:#FFD700;
       width:60px;
       float:left;
       position: relative;
       top: -35px;
       margin-right:5px;
   }
   #content{
       background-color:#EEEEEE;
       min-height:200px;
       width:895px;
       float:left;
       position: relative;
       top: -35px;
  }                  
  #footer {  
       background-color:#FFA500;
       clear:both;
       text-align:center;                    
  }
```

Image

[image]

The space is right above the footer. The footer should actually be very close to the `content` div.

Comment: I guess that space's height is about `35px`, that's exactly the movement of `top`, you set `top:-35px` to the `#content`, note that `relative` position will still keep the original space of the element (before moving by `left` and `top`). A quick fix is to set `margin-bottom:-35px` to the `#content` however you should find some better solution.

Comment: Why is this not a good solution?

Comment: because it's not really dynamic, it's harder to maintain, it depends on the case and your requirement.

Comment: I see what you mean. But if I delete all the top values from #header,#menu,#content, the undesired space will be at the top of my div. I can't seem to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "top: xxpx"'s, add margins to elements to space them and remove margin-top and margin-bottom from Headers h1

```
   #header > h1 {
     margin-top : 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
   }
```

Fiddle (without the spacing margins)

http://jsfiddle.net/vPg6k/1/

Comment: Can you please explain why the header's margin was giving me problems? Does it have a preset >0 value or why was it occupying that space?

Comment: The margin was pushing out of the container and into the content. <h1-6> elements have margins by default (as they have a font-size).

Answer (score 1):

You've shifted some of your elements (`#header`, `#content`, `#menu`) up using `top`, but you haven't shifted `#footer` up in the same way. These elements all have `position: relative`, which causes them to move visually, but **does not change their position in the document flow**.

*However*, before you add top to the footer, you may want to take second look at why you're using `top` in the first place. If you remove `top` from all the classes, a gap appears between the content/menu and header. This gap is caused by the default margin on the h1 element in your header. If you apply the following style (and remove `top` everywhere), all the gaps should disappear.

```
#header h1 {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Most browsers have an "Web Inspector" feature that is ***incredibly*** useful for working on webpages. (Styles in particular.) If you aren't familiar with your browser's inspector, I highly recommend reading up on it. I don't know what browser you're using, so I can't send you anywhere in particular, but a quick Google should get you more details.

Comment: I did use the inspector but couldn't see or know that headers have margins.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc All right. I just wanted to make sure. It's one of those tools that can be hard to find if you aren't looking for it. It took me a minute to figure out where the spacing was coming from, but after removing all the spacing, I knew it had to be coming from *somewhere* around the header. Digging around there turned up the margin from the `h1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use these styles for the `#footer`:

```
#footer
{
    background-color:#FFA500;
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    top:-30px;
}
```

That will move the footer 30 pixels up

Comment: It will, but the space will be under the footer then. Already tried that before. Also, got my answer. Just need its explanation.

Comment: Yea true, but it fixes the problem too :P

Answer (score -2):

You might want to add height to the footer.  Right now it is referencing the Font for the height.

Comment: I don't think that gives me my problem.

Comment: He wants to move his footer, not resize it.